# How to copy queues from one Service Bus to another?

Tags: azure, servicebus

I have `ServiceBus-Dev` with a lot of queues created during the development phase.

I need to create the same queues on `ServiceBus-Prod`.

Is there an easy way to copy-paste all queues from one Service Bus to another?

The only approach I found so far is to use `az cli` and write some script like:

1. Get all queues id's from both Service Buses `az servicebus queue list`
2. Write some logic to identify which queues are missing on Prod
3. Create queues that are missing one by one `az servicebus queue create`

Is there an easier way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to copy-paste all queues from one Service Bus to another?

You can use ARM Template to create and deploy infrastructure. More about [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/)

1. Create a Service bus.
2. Creates Queses

[image]

3. Go to the resource group and select service bus.

[image]
4. click on three dots on the right-hand side. and select the Export template.

[image]

5. ARM template export

[image]

6. ARM template JSON.

```json
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"namespaces_punitmt_name": {
"defaultValue": "punitmt",
"type": "String"
}

},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
{
"type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
"apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
"name": "[parameters('namespaces_punitmt_name')]",
"location": "East US",
"sku": {
"name": "Standard",
"tier": "Standard"
},

"properties": {
"minimumTlsVersion": "1.2",
"publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
"disableLocalAuth": false,
"zoneRedundant": false
}
},

{
"type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules",
"apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
"name": "[concat(parameters('namespaces_punitmt_name'), '/RootManageSharedAccessKey')]",
"location": "East US",
"dependsOn": [
"[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('namespaces_punitmt_name'))]"
],
"properties": {
"rights": [
"Listen",
"Manage",
"Send"
]
}
},
{
"type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/networkRuleSets",
"apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
"name": "[concat(parameters('namespaces_punitmt_name'), '/default')]",
"location": "East US",
"dependsOn": [
"[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('namespaces_punitmt_name'))]"
],
"properties": {
"publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
"defaultAction": "Allow",
"virtualNetworkRules": [],
"ipRules": []
}
},
{
"type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues",
"apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
"name": "[concat(parameters('namespaces_punitmt_name'), '/message1')]",
"location": "eastus",
"dependsOn": [
"[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('namespaces_punitmt_name'))]"
],
"properties": {
"maxMessageSizeInKilobytes": 256,
"lockDuration": "PT30S",
"maxSizeInMegabytes": 1024,
"requiresDuplicateDetection": false,
"requiresSession": false,
"defaultMessageTimeToLive": "P14D",
"deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration": false,
"enableBatchedOperations": true,
"duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "PT10M",
"maxDeliveryCount": 10,
"status": "Active",
"autoDeleteOnIdle": "P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S",
"enablePartitioning": false,
"enableExpress": false
}
},
{
"type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues",
"apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
"name": "[concat(parameters('namespaces_punitmt_name'), '/message2')]",
"location": "eastus",
"dependsOn": [
"[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('namespaces_punitmt_name'))]"
],
"properties": {
"maxMessageSizeInKilobytes": 256,
"lockDuration": "PT30S",
"maxSizeInMegabytes": 1024,
"requiresDuplicateDetection": false,
"requiresSession": false,
"defaultMessageTimeToLive": "P14D",
"deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration": false,
"enableBatchedOperations": true,
"duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "PT10M",
"maxDeliveryCount": 10,
"status": "Active",
"autoDeleteOnIdle": "P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S",
"enablePartitioning": false,
"enableExpress": false
}
}
]
}
```

7. You can these ARM templates where you want to create the same.